# calculating % between two rows of one column in a sql table in sequence and add to another column

Tags: mysql

table: stock_data

id | price | %change ...Each row has a unique id: 1,2,3,4, a stock price: 10.50, 11.40, 10.20, 11.60 and i would like a select statement outputs the %change to its column using a correlated sub-query.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to achieve.  Nor can I tell what you've already tried.

Comment: the basic equation is ((x.price / y.price) - 1)

Comment: i can achieve this in excel  very fast but sql is much more granular

Answer (score 0):

you should join a table with itself, but joining condition should be such, that each row is joining with a next row.

```
update stock_data a, stock_data b
set a.change_percent = b.stock_price*100/a.stock_price
where a.id = b.id +1 ;
```

change the calculation of change_percent to whatever you want it to be